# Windows username in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know how I can access the windows username in VBA, I mean the username that is displayed on this picture below :

[image]

I give this precision because I've tried using `Environ("Username")`, but that gives the login that I have to enter to start windows which is different from the name I want.

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/161394

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use a function like this:

```
Public Function GetUserDisplayName() As String
    GetUserDisplayName = GetObject("LDAP://" & CreateObject("ADSystemInfo").UserName).DisplayName
End Function
```